# How can I find the different points of a system of equations?

Tags: r, regression

I've got to solve this system of equations:

> aQ + bP = c
> dQ + eP = f

I have to find 100 values Q and P that solve the systems with 100 randomly drawn coefficients from the following distributions:

> a ~ N( 100; 10)
>
> b ~ N(-1;0.1)
>
> c ~ N(10;1)
>
> d ~ N(10;0.1)
>
> e ~ N(100;10)
>
> f ~ N(10;0.1)

Which I did by doing the following:

```
a<-rnorm(100,mean=100,sd=10)
b<-rnorm(100,mean=-1,sd=.1)
c<-rnorm(100,mean=10,sd=1)
d<-rnorm(100,mean=10,0.1)
e<-rnorm(100,mean=100,sd=10)
f<-rnorm(100,mean=10,0.1)
```

Then I made matrix:

```
O <- matrix(data=c(a,b,c),1,1)
P<- matrix(c(d,e,f),1,1)
```

Finally solved it using:

```
solve(O,P)
```

My problem is that I'm trying to get 100 solutions but this code returns just one solution. After obtaining the 100 values for Q and P I need to make a plot with all of the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replicate` to repeatedly solve your system, each time using a different random draw for the coefficients:

```
QP <- t(replicate(100, solve(rbind(c(rnorm(1, 100, 10), rnorm(1, -1, 0.1)),
                                   c(rnorm(1, 10, .1), rnorm(1, 100, 10))),
                             c(rnorm(1, 10, 1), rnorm(1, 10, 0.1)))))
colnames(QP) <- c("Q", "P")
plot(QP)
```

[image]