# How to solve a set of Linear equations?

Tags: r, equation

I need to solve a system of linear equations:

```
aQ + bP = c
dQ + eP = f
```

Where:

```
a ~ N(100;10)
b ~ N(-1;0.1)
c ~ N(10;1)
d ~ N(10;0.1)
e ~ N(100;10)
f ~ N(10;0.1)
```

So far I have written:

```
a <- rnorm(100, mean=100, sd=10)
b <- rnorm(100, mean=-1, sd=0.1)
c <- rnorm(100, mean=10, sd=1)
d <- rnorm(100, mean=10, sd=0.1)
e <- rnorm(100, mean=100, sd=10)
f <- rnorm(100, mean=10, sd=0.1)

P <- vector()
Q <- vector()

for (i in 1:100) {
    coefs <- matrix(c(a[i],d[i],b[i],e[i]),2,2)
    ys <- array(c(c,f),2)
    solve(coefs[i], ys[i])
}
```

The problem is that the for loop is only giving me one solution for P and Q and I would like that the for loop to calculate the 100 set of values do a, b, c, d, e and f and store the data on the vectors Q and P.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30652116/how-can-i-find-the-different-points-of-a-system-of-equations/30652688 for another solution (the problems look to be identical).

Comment: Thanks josilber, it's the same problem and it looks well solved as well.

Comment: @loop420 Minor point, but when you call `vector()` without specifying the `mode` argument, it defaults to logical, which is clearly not what you want. Instead, either specify `vector('double')` or `vector('numeric')` or `double()` or `numeric()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using `apply()`

```
# data  
df = data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,f)

# apply function
out = t(apply(df, 1, 
      function(x){ 
      coefs = matrix( c(x['a'], x['d'], x['b'], x['e']), 2, 2); 
      ys = array(c(x['c'],x['f']),2); 
      out = solve(coefs, ys); 
      names(out) = c('P','Q');
      out}))
```

Or else using `sapply()`

```
out = t(sapply(seq(100), function(i){
       coefs = matrix(c(a[i], d[i], b[i] ,e[i]),2,2); ys = array(c(c[i],f[i]),2);
       out = solve(coefs, ys); names(out) = c('P','Q'); 
       out}))
```

and if you want to use `for` loop, here is what you could do

```
# declare matrix to store the output
out = matrix(ncol=2, nrow=100) 

# populate declared matrix using for loop
for(i in 1:100){  
    coefs = matrix(c(a[i],d[i],b[i],e[i]),2,2)
    ys = array(c(c[i],f[i]),2)
    out[i,] = as.vector(solve(coefs, ys))
    colnames(out) = c('P','Q')
    out}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to offer another possible approach, you could use `mapply()` to effectively iterate over each coefficient and RHS vector in parallel:

```
set.seed(1);
a <- rnorm(100,100,10);
b <- rnorm(100,-1,0.1);
c <- rnorm(100,10,1);
d <- rnorm(100,10,0.1);
e <- rnorm(100,100,10);
f <- rnorm(100,10,0.1);
mapply(function(a,b,c,d,e,f) solve(matrix(c(a,d,b,e),2),matrix(c(c,f),2)),a,b,c,d,e,f);
##            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]      [,4]       [,5]       [,6]       [,7]       [,8]       [,9]      [,10]      [,11]      [,12]      [,13]      [,14]      [,15]      [,16]      [,17]      [,18]      [,19]      [,20]      [,21]      [,22]      [,23]     [,24]      [,25]      [,26]      [,27]      [,28]      [,29]      [,30]     [,31]      [,32]      [,33]      [,34]      [,35]      [,36]      [,37]      [,38]      [,39]      [,40]      [,41]      [,42]      [,43]     [,44]      [,45]      [,46]      [,47]      [,48]      [,49]     [,50]      [,51]      [,52]      [,53]     [,54]      [,55]      [,56]      [,57]     [,58]      [,59]      [,60]      [,61]      [,62]      [,63]      [,64]      [,65]     [,66]      [,67]      [,68]      [,69]      [,70]      [,71]     [,72]      [,73]      [,74]      [,75]     [,76]      [,77]      [,78]      [,79]      [,80]      [,81]      [,82]      [,83]      [,84]      [,85]      [,86]      [,87]      [,88]     [,89]     [,90]     [,91]      [,92]      [,93]      [,94]      [,95]      [,96]      [,97]      [,98]      [,99]     [,100]
## [1,] 0.11195915 0.11550647 0.12751804 0.0841975 0.07569079 0.13696420 0.10252485 0.09894877 0.09515799 0.10922284 0.08629273 0.10113763 0.10308528 0.11216529 0.09963416 0.11659483 0.09791256 0.08081292 0.09926686 0.09472402 0.07648024 0.09355051 0.09391840 0.1219382 0.08409615 0.11939194 0.09931966 0.09958410 0.10817085 0.09947289 0.0803567 0.07280706 0.09108175 0.10730635 0.11623282 0.10439468 0.11082056 0.08964156 0.10089985 0.09365293 0.10998488 0.11389442 0.09656601 0.0872372 0.12093390 0.08759978 0.09202209 0.09137391 0.10043375 0.1025373 0.09823991 0.11186173 0.09698966 0.1112308 0.09463053 0.09386283 0.07966344 0.1193879 0.09922995 0.09776010 0.08903184 0.09724774 0.09156914 0.10903049 0.12760021 0.1014739 0.11805636 0.07770935 0.09601201 0.07510938 0.09370570 0.1130247 0.08705415 0.14043486 0.11704624 0.1091617 0.08154497 0.10810454 0.08690775 0.11685334 0.11133037 0.09817079 0.10215157 0.11097263 0.08957527 0.08781713 0.08506901 0.11398943 0.1017468 0.1080845 0.1026900 0.09321191 0.09276108 0.08089681 0.10226763 0.09705664 0.12423443 0.11736748 0.11432446 0.10282015
## [2,] 0.08016778 0.07420647 0.09132015 0.0953508 0.09734921 0.09111316 0.09172938 0.09253545 0.08018053 0.09452145 0.09233637 0.08349215 0.07979583 0.09634328 0.09443451 0.08404651 0.08153545 0.09468065 0.10482579 0.07829014 0.08002979 0.09773864 0.09023393 0.1070831 0.08657002 0.07433625 0.10757136 0.09891601 0.09612082 0.09671603 0.1139721 0.08951823 0.10746614 0.08889339 0.08501627 0.09050828 0.08181816 0.09255519 0.09681833 0.08489033 0.09251537 0.07567294 0.09099927 0.0841442 0.08769969 0.13057528 0.10425570 0.09546615 0.08564604 0.1174630 0.08258592 0.09420732 0.09640516 0.1048073 0.10757819 0.08931113 0.08544322 0.1124914 0.09978848 0.08516907 0.09438840 0.07408315 0.08145526 0.08357922 0.08661255 0.0884171 0.09454044 0.08658720 0.07824592 0.08435285 0.09760972 0.1068059 0.09319386 0.08188822 0.07865432 0.1037524 0.08916170 0.08914854 0.07982980 0.08718701 0.09064425 0.10193109 0.09645453 0.09396509 0.07402690 0.07399806 0.09308106 0.09940533 0.1126132 0.0841854 0.1002329 0.07365820 0.10095744 0.08985023 0.06348183 0.10252098 0.08397957 0.09875275 0.08654524 0.09736881
```

Or if you prefer getting the results as a list, you could pass `SIMPLIFY=F` to `mapply()`, or just use `Map()`, which doesn't simplify by default:

```
Map(function(a,b,c,d,e,f) solve(matrix(c(a,d,b,e),2),matrix(c(c,f),2)),a,b,c,d,e,f);
## [[1]]
##            [,1]
## [1,] 0.11195915
## [2,] 0.08016778
##
## [[2]]
##            [,1]
## [1,] 0.11550647
## [2,] 0.07420647
##
## ... (snip) ...
##
## [[99]]
##            [,1]
## [1,] 0.11432446
## [2,] 0.08654524
##
## [[100]]
##            [,1]
## [1,] 0.10282015
## [2,] 0.09736881
```